# what is the best way to replace <font color: red>text </font> in css and HTML5

Tags: css, html

I have the below text example and I am trying to pass the w3C validator, how can I replace the below obsolete `<font>` in html5 and CSS? I hate to use `<p>` or `<h1,2,3>` any other easier option?

```
Tell us <font color="red"> why </font> you bought the product, and <font color="red"> when </font> you bought it.
```

Comment: So you've tried nothing and you're all out of ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `span`:

```
Tell us <span style="color: red;"> why </span> 
you bought the product, and <span style="color: red;"> when </span> you bought it.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
<style>
    em.highlight: {
        color: red;
        font-style: normal;
    }
</style>

...

Tell us <em class="highlight"> why </em> you bought the product, and <em class="highlight"> when </em> you bought it.
```

I used `<em>` because you're trying to *em*phasize certain words.

Comment: This is a good solution, however <em> also makes the text italic by default. I think <span> is more appropriate here.

Comment: `<strong>` might be better than `<em>` here....but it's a close semantic call. Of course, they both have default styling that might have to be overidden,